# How to use resetiosflags to reset ostream flags?

Tags: c++, c++11

I tried using this, but encountered a compilation error.  Unfortunately, I'm new to the compiler and don't understand the message.  I'm trying to get the default &ostream flags back.  Does anyone know how to properly reset the flags and what the error is reporting?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int v = 0xFF;
    cout << "0x" << hex << v << resetiosflags(hex) << v << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Compilation:

```
clang++ -Wall -std=c++11 -pedantic test251.cc && ./a.out
test251.cc:8:33: error: no matching function for call to 'resetiosflags'
    cout << "0x" << hex << v << resetiosflags(hex) << v << endl;
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../include/c++/8/iomanip:66:3: note: 
      candidate function not viable: no known conversion from
      'std::ios_base &(std::ios_base &)' to 'ios_base::fmtflags' (aka
      'std::_Ios_Fmtflags') for 1st argument
  resetiosflags(ios_base::fmtflags __mask)
  ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: You could just do: `cout << "0x" << hex << v << dec << v << endl;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key part is this:

```
candidate function not viable: no known conversion from
      'std::ios_base &(std::ios_base &)' to 'ios_base::fmtflags'
```

that's telling you that `resetiosflags` takes a `fmtflags` instance but you tried to pass it a *function* that returns an `ios_base`. It's a bit confusing but `std::hex` is a [stream manipulator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/library/manipulators/) which is actually a function while `std::ios_base::hex` is a `std::ios_base::fmtflags` instance and that's what you need to be passing to `resetiosflags`.

Specifically (not tested) I think this will do what you want:

```
int main()
{
    int v = 0xFF;
    cout << "0x" << hex << v << resetiosflags(std::ios_base::hex)
        << v << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Or just `resetiosflags(ios_base::hex)` since `using namespace std;` is being used.  Or, you can even use `resetiosflags(cout.hex)` since the `hex` flag is available as a static constant in `std::ios_base` which `std::cout` derives from, and statics can be accessed as object members.